# jQuery selector for li in ul li

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I create a menu & want to when click on li children just child set .active class no li parent

(Use in enfold WordPress theme)

```js
$('#mobile-advanced li.menu-item-has-children').on('click', function () {
   $(this).toggleClass('active');
});

// just for test
$('a').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault() ;
});
```

```css
li.active{
  background-color: #FFB94B;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="mobile-advanced">
  <li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children">
    <a href="">T 1</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children">
        <a href="">T11</a>
        <ul>
          <li class="menu-item"><a href="">T111</a></li>
          <li class="menu-item"><a href="">T112</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-item"><a href="">T12</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item"><a href="">T13</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-item">
    <a href="">T 2</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

for example, when I click li children li parent set active class
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: demo works as expected ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can detect event `click` with `a` tags :

```js
$('#mobile-advanced li.menu-item-has-children a').on('click', function () {
   $(this).parent().toggleClass('active');
});

// just for test
$('a').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault() ;
});
```

```css
li.active{
  background-color: #FFB94B;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="mobile-advanced">
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children">
                <a href="">T 1</a>
                <ul>
                    <li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children">
                        <a href="">T11</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li class="menu-item"><a href="">T111</a></li>
                            <li class="menu-item"><a href="">T112</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="menu-item"><a href="">T12</a></li>
                    <li class="menu-item"><a href="">T13</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="menu-item">
                <a href="">T 2</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: If you add `$('li.active').toggleClass('active');` it will limit the **active** `class` to one element at a time. [**JsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lsezdf1x/)

Answer (score 1):

You just need add another class into the element you want to change. In my case, i define anther class called "active-this"  and  apply the jquery function to this class. Follow the example:

```
 $('.active-this').on('click', function () {
   $(this).toggleClass('active');
});

// just for test
$('a').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault() ;
});



li.active{
  background-color: #FFB94B;
}


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="mobile-advanced">
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children">
            <a href="">T 1</a>
            <ul>
                <li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children">
                    <a href="">T11</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="menu-item active-this"><a href="">T111</a></li>
                        <li class="menu-item active-this"><a href="">T112</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item active-this"><a href="">T12</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item active-this"><a href="">T13</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item">
            <a href="">T 2</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below selector to be able to click on `li` menu items excluding parent `li` elements.

`$('#mobile-advanced li.menu-item').not(".menu-item-has-children")`

```js
$('#mobile-advanced li.menu-item').not(".menu-item-has-children").on('click', function (e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 $(this).toggleClass('active');
});

$(".menu-item-has-children").on('click', function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
})
```

```css
li.active {
 background-color: #FFB94B;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="mobile-advanced">
 <li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children">
  <a href="">T 1</a>
  <ul>
   <li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children">
    <a href="">T11</a>
    <ul>
     <li class="menu-item">
      <a href="">T111</a>
     </li>
     <li class="menu-item">
      <a href="">T112</a>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li class="menu-item">
    <a href="">T12</a>
   </li>
   <li class="menu-item">
    <a href="">T13</a>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li class="menu-item">
  <a href="">T 2</a>
 </li>
</ul>
```